# How can I integrate $\int \frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}}dx\;$?

Tags: integration

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos{x}}}dx$$
Does a closed form exist for this integral? It has withstood every integration technique I know and WA shows an error ("try the following.." etc)

Comment: Are you sure it hasn't been given the integration limits?

Answer (score 1):

Dividing top and bottom by $\sqrt{\sin x}$ you have
$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{\sin x} + \sqrt{\cos x}} \ dx
 = \int \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{\cot x}} \ dx
$$